# How GAE emulator limits list of available Python modules?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I installed Python Mock module using PIP.

When I try to `import mock` running under 'dev_appserver', GAE says that it can't find module 'mock'.

`import mock` works perfectly in Python interpreter.

I understand that `dev_appserver` behaves absolutely correctly because I can't install modules with PIP on GAE servers.

My question is how *technically* `dev_appserver` filters list of modules that can be loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev_appserver uses [import hooks](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) to prevent importing modules that shouldn't be available. The relevant code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py#1287), but be warned - it's easily the most complicated bit of the dev_appserver!